# If we add all three-element cycles to this set, do we get a subgroup of S4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

So I've got two questions.

a)Is the set $\{e,(1, 2)(3, 4),(1, 3)(2, 4),(1, 4)(2, 3)\}$ with permutation folding operation a subgroup of the $S_4$ group?

b)If we add all three-element cycles to this set, do we get a subgroup of $S_4$?

So a) is trivial, we just need a table. But I've a problem to show b) without drawing a table because it's too much. Combining all elements the order of the group is $12$. I wanted to find a counterexample but I haven't found any.

Comment: What do you mean by permutation **folding** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3-cycles, there are totally $$\frac{4!}{3^1\cdot 1!}=8$$

conjugacy elements, and they are all even-permutations. And you have found all 2-2 cycles, totally three, and they are all even-permutations. So totally we have

$$1+3+8=12$$

where $1$ represents the unit element. These $12$ elements are half of $24=|S_4|$ and they are all even-permutations, hence form the $A_4$, which is a subgroup of $S_4$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $12$ elements are exactly the even permutations in $S_4$, so they form the alternating subgroup $A_4.$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about $A_4$, you must check the closure (which, on the other hand, suffices), namely you have to "draw a table". Btw, once you have proved that they both are subgroups, you can notice that both are union of conjugacy classes, and hence they are normal in $S_4$.